# Path with min traveled edges and max weight in undirected weighted graph

Tags: graph-theory, shortest-path, dijkstra, undirected-graph

I'm trying to work out an algorithm for finding a path across an undirected graph. It's not a conventional path and I can't find any references to anything like this being done already.

My goal is to find a path with the minimum traveled edges (jumps between vertices) and the maximum weight of this path (prevalence is in minimum traveled edges). The algorithm should check first all the paths with minimum traveled edges and then choose which of these paths has the maximum weight. For example, two minimum traveled edges paths are {3->4->5} and {5->6->3} algorithm should take path 2, since total weight is 14, while in the first is 12.

It would be really useful if anyone could provide me references of similar material or a way to work this out.

Comment: A breadth-first-search will find the path/s with minimum edges. Then you can literally add the weights for each path and take the max. Is that not efficient enough in your case?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that in your problem you are given a pair of vertices in the graph `s` and `t`, and you are to find the shortest path in the sense as described in your problem. I will also assume that all the weights are positive, but even if they are not, adding a sufficiently large number to every edge weight does not change the output path and makes every edge weight positive. Then the following will work and a Dijkstra algorithm can be used.

The problem can be solved by putting different weights on the edges and then just finding the path of minimum weight as follows.

If `W` is the sum of the weights of all the edges in the graph, then putting `new_weight(e)` of `W-weight(e)`, where `weight(e)` is the old weight, on every edge `e` gives the desired outcome.

Indeed, a minimum weight path `P` between `s` and `t` will have the weight between `kW` and `(k-1)W`, where `k` is the total number of *jumps* on the path. So, the total weight of the path `P` will be `kW-s`, where `s` is the sum of the old edge weights on the path `P`. Here, we are effectively minimizing `-s` or equivalently maximizing `s`.